# seeding not possible (says that file is missing)

Tags: php, laravel

I just encountered a strange problem. While migrations work flawlessly I can't seed a thing. I rebased the project from git, ran composer update, generated a key migrated everything and when I tried to seed them I got this:

> include(C:\Users\nathaniel\Desktop\LaraProjects\Scattegories\vendor\composer/../../atabase/seeds/DatabaseSeeder.php):
>   fa   iled to open stream: No such file or directory

Ive tried to google the problem already but I couldn't find anything on this! Hope you guys can help me solve this.

Comment: What code are you using to get this error?

Comment: What do you mean? It php artisan db:seed

Comment: Check your path because it should be 'database' not 'atabase'

Comment: Well i dont know how to check the path for seeder but in project the folder is called database not atabase

Comment: try this command `composer dumpautoload` then `php artisan db:seed`

Comment: tried it already same thing

Comment: Well does file `C:\Users\nathaniel\Desktop\LaraProjects\Scattegories\atabase\seeds\DatabaseSeeder.php` exist?

Comment: I see that your seeding is taking both windows path and unix path i.e. forward & backward slash `/` & `\'. fix them first from your `.env` file. I am not sure but may be you have to delete vendor folder and do a `composer install`.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following command in your CLI (first change to the project directory)

```
composer dump-autoload
```

or

```
composer dumpautoload
```

It should clear the composer cache.

Comment: Did you try `php artisan cache:clear`? anyway, do you have the DatabaseSeeder.php file at all?

Comment: Just tried that, not working, yes i do have datebaseseeder in my seeds folder

Comment: `composer dumpautoload` should do the work for you, are you sure you running this command on the project directory?

Comment: Something wrong as it is looking for 'atabase' folder instead of 'database' folder.

Comment: Do you have any idea on what could be causing this ?

Answer (score 0):

The file is missing, since there is a typo in the path of

> include(C:\Users\nathaniel\Desktop\LaraProjects\Scattegories\vendor\composer/../../**atabase**/seeds/DatabaseSeeder.php):
>   fa iled to open stream: No such file or directory

The path above misses a d in database

Comment: i know that but in the project the file is named database and when i rename it to atabase it works. What could cause this problem ?

Comment: @Cadilab the source-code expects atabase somewhere. Search for /atabase in the whole project to find the bug.